# Why does a custom directive links even though ng-attr resolves to undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom (attribute) directive which I wish to either have or remove based on a condition.

I'm using `ng-attr-my-directive="{{true ? undefined : 'value'}}"`.

The attribute is missing from the element as expected however `myDirective`'s link function still runs. I tried changing the priority of `myDirective` but it didn't help.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue? Is it a bug? If not, what's the logic behind this behaviour?

Full example: https://codepen.io/krulik/pen/bWzNYG

Comment: What about an inner scope with `{myDirective: '='}`? Are you showing us a simplified example, or this is the actual functionality required from the directive?

Comment: @AlonEitan Yes, it's simplified but it doesn't matter at all what the directive does. I need a general and simple way to conditionally load a directive from outside. Isolated scope doesn't help, it's still linked (example updated). Thanks